# Cannot delete post despite correct permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post an image to my feed (via the FB Graph API), do something with it, and then delete said image. Now I am able to successfully post the image but when I try to delete it, I get an error saying

> (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

[According to the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/post), I need the `publish_actions` permission to delete posts - a post that was made by the app (for the purpose of testing, I'm using a short access token created via the Graph API Explorer), no less. I already have the permission requested and removed and re-requested it but to no avail.

Following is the relevant code:

```
// Post the image to the private feed
res, err := fb.Post("/me/photos", fb.Params{
    "source":       fb.File("najm.jpg"),
    "access_token": os.Getenv("FB_ACCESSTOKEN"),
})

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error posting image:", err)
}

log.Println("The uploaded image's post_id is:", res["post_id"])
log.Println("Now deleting the aformentioned image from the feed.")

// Delete the image
res2, err2 := fb.Delete(res["post_id"].(string), fb.Params{
    "access_token": os.Getenv("FB_ACCESSTOKEN"),
})

log.Fatalln("Error deleting image:", err2)
log.Println("Returned response after deletion:", res2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. To delete the image, I needed to pass the picture id `pid` instead of the post id `post_id`.